# How to read a text file ,turn it into a string, then using arguments on it

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, arguments

Say If I had a string = "There were %@ apples,I ate %@. Now I have %@ apples" in text file "Apples.txt". This is how I will extract the text from it.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Apples" ofType:@"txt"];
NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

Now how do I pass the arguments to it so it looks like this:
"There were %@ apples,I ate %@. Now I have %@ apples", x, y, x-y

I am sure there is a way around this using NString with arguments? using 
NSString with local argument functions? otherwise I will have to type all of my text in the file.m

This very crucial for my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for `[NSString stringWithFormat:...]`.

```
Your complete code goes like this :

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Apples" ofType:@"txt"];
NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

NSNumber *total = @100;
NSNumber *ate = @34;

NSString *fullString = [NSString stringWithFormat:content,total,ate, @([total integerValue] - [ate integerValue])];

NSLog(@"%@", fullString);
```

***Output:***

```
"There were 100 apples,I ate 34. Now I have 66 apples".
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `+ stringWithFormat:`

Here's the [Apple reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html)