# How to pass NSString as arguments with formatWithString?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, arguments, stringwithformat

This is a fundamental part of my app, infact it is a function.

```
-(void)appendArguments:(NSString *)argument {
NSString *temp = [NSString stringWithFormat:_path, argument;
}
```

But this is not possible. Here _path is an instance variable that holds a string with integer arguments. The string argument holds integers, for example:

```
_path = @"I got %d apples, ate %d, I am left with %d";
argument = @"7,3,7-3";
*temp = [NSString stringWithFormat:_path, argument;
```

Can we make an array of arguments as objects, and replace them with pointer argument.

My app is now on hold because of this.

Comment: it looks like very similar to this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27269587/how-to-read-a-text-file-turn-it-into-a-string-then-using-arguments-on-it/27269750#27269750

Comment: It is now not similar, as this a function call with any number of arguments.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the `va_list`.

```
void myLog(NSString *format, ...)
{
#ifdef DEBUG
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, format);
    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:format arguments:ap];
    fprintf(stdout, "%s", string.UTF8String);
    va_end(ap);
#endif
}


@implementation MyViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    myLog(@"%s, %@\n", __func__, self);
}
```

Comment: Please further elaborate with an example, I have never seen it before and I am new to Objective C.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Can you give me an example with that?

Comment: @VideoGamingIOs: google it(objective-c variable argument) friend.

Comment: I am using this for NSLog replacement that prints stdout etc. It can work within a pure Objective-C source file. I don't know that it is useful for others, though:)

Comment: @VideoGamingIOs I edited the code. You can call `appendArguments(@"I got %d %@, ate %d.", 7, @"apples", 3)` then it will be printed in the stdout instead of NSLog's default output.

Comment: @VideoGamingIOs I tried to edit it again. Is it be clear? I am not good for English, Thanks for reading!

Comment: @mag. does not work when I want to return the String, gives me lots of problems as Expected method body, use of undeclaerd identifier format!,etc

Comment: @VideoGamingIOs Hummmm it's strange... Can I see your code?

Comment: @mag. here you go:
- (NSString *) appendArguments(NSString *format, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, format);
    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:format arguments:ap];
    fprintf(stdout, "%s", string.UTF8String);
    va_end(ap);
    return string;
}

Comment: @VideoGamingIOs OK. Your first line is mixed with C and Objective-C. Try this. `- (NSString *)appendArguments:(NSString *)format, ...` that is written by pure Objective-C.

Comment: @mag. does not give me errors, but can you givew me an example like how I did in my question?

Comment: @mag. NSString *path = @"I got %d apples, ate %d and now have left %d apples";
    NSArray *array = @[@"7", @"4", @"7-4"];
    NSString *answer = [NSString appendArguments:path,array]; gives me I got -24067104 apples, ate 2 and now have left -2 apples

Comment: @VideoGamingIOs Wait a minute, I will check the code.

Comment: @mag. Works, sorry I used int as arguments.

Comment: @mag. I need to now figure out how to convert these arguments to integer, you have been a grat help, if this app succeeds I may give you some % of it.

Comment: @mag. can I please have your personal e-mail. Thank you very very much, a lifesaver. Everything worked

Comment: Wow! Congratulations! I'm so happy just to help you. No problem. Thanks:D

Comment: Who the heck down-voted this answer - it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it. Use `NSMutableString` and append string to make a custom format for string.

```
NSString *_path = @"I got %d apples, ate %d, I am left with %d";
NSString *argument = @"7,3,7,-3";

NSMutableString *fieldString = [NSMutableString new];
[fieldString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"@\" %@\" ",_path]];
[fieldString appendString:@","];
[fieldString appendString:argument];

NSString *strField = [NSString stringWithString:fieldString];
fieldString = nil;
```

Comment: thank you, but does not work with infinite arguments.

Answer (score 0):

```
     NSString* arguments = @"7,3,7-3";
        [self appendArguments:arguments];

    -(void)appendArguments:(NSString *)argument {

    NSString* _path = @"I got %d apples, ate %d, I am left with %d-%d";
     NSArray*path=[[NSArray alloc]init];
     path=[argument componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
 NSString *temp = [NSString stringWithFormat:_path, [path[0] intValue],[path[1]   intValue],[path[0] intValue],[path[1] intValue] ];

    NSLog(@"%@",temp);

            }
```

the result

```
I got 7 apples, ate 3, I am left with 7-3
```